# CakePHP - How to call JS function when ajax request is completed

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How can i call a JS function when the ajax request is completed

I'm Using Js helper and RequestHandler Component

**This is my view file**

```
<?php echo $this->Js->submit('Create User', array(
    'before'=>$this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeIn'),
    'success'=>$this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeOut'),
    'update'=>'#success',
)); 
?>
```

i'm getting a loading message and success message...
I want to call a JS function when the ajax request is done/completed, so that i can close the User registration DIV

Answer (score 3):

i solved it...there is a method in Js Helper called **complete** and we can call JS function

```
<?php echo $this->Js->submit('Create User', array(
    'before'=>$this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeIn'),
    'success'=>$this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeOut'),
    'update'=>'#success',
    'complete' => 'self.setInterval("test()",2000);'
));
```

test() will be called after ajax request is completed.